# In R using data.table, how does one exclude rows and how does one include NA values in an integer column

Tags: r, select, data.table, subset

I am  using data.table quite a lot. It works well but I am finding it is taking me a long time to transition my syntax so that it takes advantage of the binary searching.

In the following data table how would 1 select all the rows, including where the CPT value is `NA` but exclude rows where the CPT value is 23456 or 10000.

```
cpt <- c(23456,23456,10000,44555,44555,NA)
description <- c("tonsillectomy","tonsillectomy in >12 year old","brain transplant","castration","orchidectomy","miscellaneous procedure")
cpt.desc <- data.table(cpt,description)

setkey(cpt.desc,cpt)
```

The following line works but I think it uses the vector scan method instead of a binary search (or binary exclusion). Is there a way to to drop rows by binary methods?

```
cpt.desc[!cpt %in% c(23456,10000),]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a partial answer, because I am new to data.table. A self-join works for number, but the same fails for strings. I am sure one of the professional data tablers knows what to do.

```
library(data.table)

n <- 1000000
cpt.desc <- data.table(
  cpt=rep(c(23456,23456,10000,44555,44555,NA),n),
  description=rep(c("tonsillectomy","tonsillectomy in >12 year old","brain transplant","castration","orchidectomy","miscellaneous procedure"),n))

# Added on revision. Not very elegant, though. Faster by factor of 3
# but probably better scaling 
setkey(cpt.desc,cpt)
system.time(a<-cpt.desc[-cpt.desc[J(23456,45555),which=TRUE]])
system.time(b<-cpt.desc[!(cpt %in% c(23456,45555))] )
str(a)
str(b)

identical(as.data.frame(a),as.data.frame(b))

# A self-join works Ok with numbers
setkey(cpt.desc,cpt)
system.time(a<-cpt.desc[cpt %in% c(23456,45555),])
system.time(b<-cpt.desc[J(23456,45555)])
str(a)
str(b)

identical(as.data.frame(a),as.data.frame(b)[,-3])

# But the same failes with characters
setkey(cpt.desc,description)
system.time(a<-cpt.desc[description %in% c("castration","orchidectomy"),])
system.time(b<-cpt.desc[J("castration","orchidectomy"),])
identical(as.data.frame(a),as.data.frame(b)[,-3])

str(a)
str(b)
```

Comment: your code selects for certain values. However I am trying to select against (or exclude or drop) rows with certain values.

Comment: There are still problems with your code. When you setup the data table you used 44555 as a value but I thing you committed a typographical error in the subsequent lines because you used 45555. Furthermore, when you want to use an OR function in the J command you cannot use `J(first value,second value)` since that will look for the first value in the first key and the second value in the second key. Instead you have to use `J(c(first value,second value))`. Check it out and see if you agree. After that I will look again. I am intrigued by your technique.

Comment: Hi all. Dieter's `cpt.desc[-cpt.desc[J(23456,45555),which=TRUE]])` was pretty close. Just needs `c()` as Farrel points out. Agree it's not pretty; [FR#1384](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1384&group_id=240&atid=978) should solve that.